# How to capture "screenshot" from current Program Monitor output?

Tags: adobe, adobe-premiere

Is it possible to capture a "screenshot" of the current Program Monitor view through a custom Premiere Pro extension?

In the end I would ideally like access to it as a base64  encoded string (png or jpg) of the current view.

The closest I've found is in a demo extension panel with "Save sequence frame as .png" which opens the Media Encoder window.

Code: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/blob/e60d6a22ef44d8eb4cca3904c35a0c050576b697/PProPanel/index.html#L264-L292

Screenshot:
[image: clicking save sequence frame button]